# I can't update nor install themes , everytime I do , it displays this error

Tags: apt, updates, update-manager, manpage

```
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

. literally for everything update related . please if you will answer tell me what to delete and how . cause I am new to this and thanks
I removed some Ts to post it ,cause I don't have enough reputation
here , sorry again.

```
Ign:1 http://ppa.launchpad.net/noobslab/themes/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
Get:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease [114 kB]
Err:4 http://ppa.launchpad.net/noobslab/themes/ubuntu focal Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.85 80]
Get:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease [108 kB]
Get:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease [114 kB]
Get:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main i386 Packages [616 kB]
Get:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 Packages [1,641 kB]
Get:9 htp://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [277 kB]
Get:10 htp://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe amd64 Packages [909 kB]
Get:11 htp://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe i386 Packages [673 kB]
Get:12 htp://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [391 kB]
Get:13 htp://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/multiverse amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [940 B]
Get:14 htp://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [7,992 B]
Get:15 htp://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [30.8 kB]
Get:16 htp://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [40.7 kB]
Get:17 htp://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [66.2 kB]
Get:18 htp://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/multiverse amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [2,464 B]
Reading package lists... Done                                                  
E: The repository 'htp://ppa.launchpad.net/noobslab/themes/ubuntu focal Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Comment: Please [edit] the question and post the complete result of `sudo apt update`. This contains everything you need to know about the errors.

Comment: Yeah, this is missing all the error messages that will tell us what is wrong. Please include the entire output.

Comment: I edited it,now

Answer (score 0):

Please check the spelling in your repository URLs. According to the error messages you posted, several of your repo URLs seem to start with `htp://`. It needs to be at least `http://`. Once you corrected this, you may need to look into encrypted connections (for those, you'll need `https://` as the protocol prefix), signed repositories and key management and so forth. But those will probably be topics of their own.

You'll find the definitions of the repositories your system "knows about" in `/etc/apt/sources.list` and/or in individual files in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`.

Comment: I removed them on purpose, the protocol here is that i have to have 10 reputation points to post more than 8 links so I deleted the Ts